# Como eu faço para o meu aplicativo fica na opções para abrir um arquivo txt

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Eu gostaria de saber como é que eu faço para que meu aplicativo venha a está na lista que opções para abrir arquivo de texto, o meu aplicativo é pequeno só para ler e editar arquivo txt para mim treinar programação, usuário vai clicar em um arquivo txt e vai abrir diretamente no meu aplicativo APK só que não consegui achar o código para fazer isso se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo peguei um códico de exemplo

**ManipuladorArquivo.java:**

```
package gomes.fernando.robson;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class ManipuladorArquivo 
{

public static void leitor(String path) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String linha = "";
    while (true) {
        if (linha != null) {
            System.out.println(linha);

        } else
            break;
        linha = buffRead.readLine();
    }
    buffRead.close();
}

public static void escritor(String path) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
    String linha = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escreva algo: ");
    linha = in.nextLine();
    buffWrite.append(linha + "\n");
    buffWrite.close();
}

}
```

**Principal.java:**

```
package gomes.fernando.robson;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Principal {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String path = "/tmp/file.txt";

    ManipuladorArquivo.escritor(path);
    ManipuladorArquivo.leitor(path);
}

}
```

Bom a classe principal vai utilizar a classe ManipuladorArquivo.java que tem como função ler e escrever o arquivo. Bom é só você tratar a leitura com a parte visual, xml ...

> Quer uma explicação mais detalhada do códico acima?
> Artigo original: https://www.devmedia.com.br/leitura-e-escrita-de-arquivos-de-texto-em-java/25529

Comment: Desculpa se não esclarecer, o que eu tava querendo não é o código para ler e escrever era como deixar meu aplicativo na lista, na opção para leitura de arquivo de texto para quando usuário pressionar um arquivo de texto o meu aplicativo aparecendo as opções para abrir com ele, mas obrigado pelo incentivo agradeço mais ainda se você conseguir me ajudar nesse ponto em específico.